# Throttling the FPS of my iOS app

Tags: ios, frame-rate, throttling

I was wondering if there was some way to throttle the FPS of my app. I've seen a lot of discussion around game libraries that can throttle their FPS to 30, but I'd like to do the same for a non-game app. I was thinking 30 would be a good number, but basically I just want to see how far down I can get it while keeping a good user experience, to see if it will save battery.

Comment: There is no notion of FPS if you are not using some sort of renderer, the screen updates when there is something to update. You may be mistaking refresh rate for fps, but that is controlled by the screens hardware.

Comment: There are still things like animations which run continuously and don't simply update immediately